# Uploaded image with non-english characters is named incorrectly in upload folder

Tags: uploads, encoding

When I upload an image with non-english characters in media uploader it gets incorrectly converted name in wordpress uploads folder but the image link in database is has correct name which results in 404 error.

For example if I upload an image with filename `obrázek.jpg`, WordPress places it to upload folder like this: `obrĂˇzek.jpg`

The link to the image in wordpress media uploader is correct though: `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/obrázek.jpg`

I have set up charsets to UTF-8 in PHP, Apache, MySQL and WordPress configuration files.

I think this has something to do with Apache. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well know issue but for some reason it is not resolved since 2013

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22363

You can always sanitized filename by yourself using `sanitize_file_name` filter.

```
/**
 * Sanitize filename to not brake links with UTF-8 characters
 *
 * WordPress allow to upload files with names containing UTF-8 characters. Some
 * browsers do not handle properly UTF-8 characters in url which causes 404 errors.
 * This filter will remove UTF-8 characters from filename before saving it.
 * 
 * @see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22363 Bug request
 *
 * @param string $filename Filename
 *
 * @return string Sanitized filename
 */
function sanitize_filename( $filename ) {
    $file_parts = explode( '.', $filename );
    $extension  = array_pop( $file_parts );
    $filename   = sanitize_title( preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', join( '.', $file_parts ) ) );

    return sprintf('%s.%s', $filename, $extension);
}

add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'sanitize_filename' );
```